# thinning / minimizing cubic spline control points ('auto-smoothing')

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, cubic-spline

### short form

Given a collection of discrete [x, y] points, can you derive a continuous function that approximates the [x, y] points and meets two constraints:

- It satisfies a given (maximum) mean squared error.
- It minimizes the number of control points.

?

### details

This is really an embedded system question, but let me explain.  I need to interface a piece of analog hardware that *cough* could have been designed better.  But -- as usual -- it's the embedded system engineer's responsibility to correct for shortcomings in the hardware.

Consequently, I need to formulate an accurate model for the following function:
[image: duty cycle vs loop current]

The blue dots are taken from actual measurement, the red line is scipy's cubic interpolation between the dots.

The problem is that the resulting 82+ control points create far too much data to stuff into the client's dinky little microcontroller.  (I'm displaying a subset of the total dataset.)

So my question is: How can I minimize the number of spline control points and stay within some given MSE?

### for the motivated

Here's the set of x and y points used in the above graph.

```
x = [ 3.387,  3.552,  3.714,  3.868,  4.012,  4.15 ,  4.278,  4.407,
      4.529,  4.646,  4.757,  4.852,  4.924,  4.974,  5.012,  5.046,
      5.084,  5.148,  5.267,  5.426,  5.593,  5.75 ,  5.9  ,  6.03 ,
      6.145,  6.26 ,  6.37 ,  6.48 ,  6.6  ,  6.72 ,  6.83 ,  6.945,
      7.055,  7.175,  7.29 ,  7.405,  7.52 ,  7.63 ,  7.75 ,  7.86 ,
      7.98 ,  8.09 ]
y = [ 0.05 ,  0.055,  0.06 ,  0.065,  0.07 ,  0.075,  0.08 ,  0.085,
      0.09 ,  0.095,  0.1  ,  0.105,  0.11 ,  0.115,  0.12 ,  0.125,
      0.13 ,  0.135,  0.14 ,  0.145,  0.15 ,  0.155,  0.16 ,  0.165,
      0.17 ,  0.175,  0.18 ,  0.185,  0.19 ,  0.195,  0.2  ,  0.205,
      0.21 ,  0.215,  0.22 ,  0.225,  0.23 ,  0.235,  0.24 ,  0.245,
      0.25 ,  0.255]
```

### ps

Note that I'm not wedded to cubic splines in particular.  I'm open to any compact representation for approximating the [x, y] function that isn't computationally expensive to expand on the microcontroller.

Comment: I stumbled across the [Ramer Douglas Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), which looks promising.  But [this entry](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1907632/153039) in math.stackexchange looks simpler and sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

When I noticed that the portion of the graph where loop current greater than 6.0 appears linear, I thought one possible approach is to to split the data set into pieces and fit those individually. Here is my attempt at doing this, with a high end piece, a low end piece, and two middle pieces. Single precision should be OK, and the client hardware can already perform numeric multiplication for the splines:

```
if x > 6.0
    a = -9.7949290874469949E-02
    b =  4.3620505659335194E-02
    y = a + bx
else if x < 4.5:
    a =  2.0780250294624176E-02
    b = -1.1030255807503962E-02
    c =  5.8098518234878981E-03
    y = a + bx + cx^2
else if x < 5.2:
    a =  1.9299476875427801E+00
    b = -8.2789734912004187E-01
    c =  9.3133373338805447E-02
    y = a + bx + cx^2
else:
    a =  5.2371635939198503E-02
    b =  3.4449759555560976E-03
    c =  2.5067846229176044E-03
    y = a + bx + cx^2
```

Comment: That looks great, but one question: how did you do the fitting?  I'm guessing you chose the partition points manually and use standard curve fitting on each region.  True?

Comment: I took the high end as a straight line,  and then split the low end manually such that the low-end pieces would be as large as practical and still give a good fit to a quadratic equation. Each of these data segments was fit by standard linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

I think cubic spline is probably the approach that best answers your question  But I also think that the question "can you derive a continuous function" and what you really want to do are not exactly the same thing.

For how to best thin your data points, I think that will require some knowledge of the system such as the expected resolution in loop current and duty cycle.  From the graph, you could probably use every other or even every third point and get good results.

But as @JamesPhillips suggests, it also looks like that you might be able to find piece-wise linear or cubic regions for the response.  If that's sufficient, then you could record the region bounds and slope/intercept/quadratic for the sub-curves, which you probably can fit in the microcontroller memory.